# xplat You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, nomachine-nx

Im trying to generate a new app using xplat

I am using node version 11.15

I try to do the following

`npx create-xplat-workspace myworkspace`

I generates everything til it prompts

`? Would you like to generate xplat supporting architecture now? You can also generate later with: nx generate @nstudio/xplat:init 
  not right now     [just add xplat tooling] 
  electron          [generate xplat Electron support] 
❯ ionic             [generate xplat Ionic support] 
  nativescript      [generate xplat NativeScript support] 
  web               [generate xplat Web support]`

I select ionic and I get the following error

`You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.`

Here is the entirety

```
`npm install -D @nstudio/xplat

> @nstudio/xplat@8.0.5 postinstall /Users/ag/nxprojects/myworkspace/node_modules/@nstudio/xplat
> node src/utils/postinstall.js

Patch for nx format have been applied

>  XPLAT  Note:

  xplat is updating "/Users/ag/nxprojects/myworkspace/.prettierignore" with a few important extra rules. You may double-check the contents afterwards to ensure they meet your satisfaction.

npm WARN acorn-dynamic-import@4.0.0 requires a peer of acorn@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ @nstudio/xplat@8.0.5
added 11 packages from 66 contributors and audited 898038 packages in 30.891s
found 1 low severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
npx nx g @nstudio/xplat:init

>  NX   NOTE  Nx didn't recognize the command, forwarding on to the Angular CLI.

? Would you like to generate xplat supporting architecture now? You can also generate later with: nx generate @nstudio/xplat:init ionic             [generate xplat Ionic support]
? Do you prefer to use a frontend framework? angular          [ensure platforms are added with Angular]
? Please input a 2-3 character prefix to use with xplat generators: ci
You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
Command failed: npx nx g @nstudio/xplat:init`
```

Comment: have the same issue did you manage to resolve

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue noticed it was failing on `nx g @nstudio/xplat:init`  but if you go into the workspace and run `ng g @nstudio/xplat:init` it then completes.